# When I run the server instead of the localhost:8000 I'm redirected to localhost:8000/app/

Tags: django

When I run the server, instead of the `localhost:8000`, I'm redirected to `localhost:8000/app/`.

```
Page not found (404)

“/home/sowou/Bureau/my_space/etude/IFNTI/stage/Django-CRM/app” does not exist

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve

Using the URLconf defined in crm.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^swagger(?P<format>\.json|\.yaml)$ [name='schema-json']
    ^swagger/$ [name='schema-swagger-ui']
    ^redoc/$ [name='schema-redoc']
    api/
    logout/ [name='logout']
    ^(?P<path>.*)$

The current path, app/, matched the last one.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Add `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'` in your settings.py. Then it will redirect you to root url after logout.

Comment: I was told my projects only has Api's urls and there is no app's url available. How do i create app's urls ?

Comment: For web view, do you have a template view for localhost:8000 ?